# Weblogic OSB Domain Configuration Error : Could not find main class com.oracle.cie.wizard.wizardController

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, osb

I have installed OSB in weblogic 10.3.6 and when I try to configure an OSB domain by running the config.cmd file from the location WL_HOME/common/bin, I am facing the below error.

Could not find the main class: com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController. Program will exit.

My JAVA_HOME is set to jdk1.6.0_45.

Can anyone please let me know what could have been the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use this script : ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/config.sh
Référence :https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/INOSB/configure_osb.htm#INOSB382

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried that. But same response :(

Comment: Can you share the complete stack trace ?

Comment: I have reinstalled the weblogic and config.cmd is just working fine. May be I would have done some thing wrong with my first installation which I am not sure of. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstalled the weblogic and things went fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try run config.cmd file as administrator